# Why is python printing multiple rows, if I only have four rows?

Tags: python

I hope someone can help with this loop. 
I have the following CSV file:

```
143560,00210,318,2,2,TRS,
143493,00210,309,6,4,TRS,             
143494,00210,309,6,4,TRS,             
143495,00210,309,10,6,TRS,
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to load each column in a variable and compare the columns TOTS and UNS row by row, then, print the remaining variables row by row.

For example, in the fourth column the evaluation goes as follow:
if 10 is not equal 6 print 143495 00210 309 TRS. I have imported the CSV and managed to place each column in a variable, but when I do the evaluation, for some unknown reason Python prints the same row multiple times ( 5 or 6 times to be precise) before moving to the other row.

Is there a way to evaluate this without printing additional rows?

```
import csv
import os
dir = "C:/Users/Hande/Desktop/try"
os.chdir(dir)
with open('pyton.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

#VARIABLE DECLARATION 
DOCS    = []
COS     = []
MICS    = []
TOTS    = []
UNS     = []
LOC_FRS = []
LOC_TOS = []

for row in readCSV:
#SETS EACH COLUNM TO AN ARRAY INDEX 
    DOC    = row[0]
    CO     = row[1]
    MIC    = row[2]
    TOT    = row[3]
    UN     = row[4]
    LOC_FR = row[5]


#APPENDS THE DATA 
    DOCS.append(DOC)
    COS.append(CO)
    MICS.append(MIC)
    TOTS.append(TOT)
    UNS.append(UN)
    LOC_FRS.append(LOC_FR)

for D in DOCS:
  for C in COS:
    for M in MICS:
      for T in TOTS:
        for U in UNS:
          for LF in LOC_FRS:
            for a, b, c, d, e, f in zip(D, C, M, T, U, LF): 
              if d != e: 
                print (D, C, M, LF)
              else:  
                print("good")
```

Comment: The code you posted does not really match your description (which I don’t fully understand) at all. You say you want to compare `TOTS` and `UNS` but why are you iterating through all those other things too? I’m confused what those things are and where they come from.

Comment: Note that it will be much easier to do these things if you read your CSV file with the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module or into [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). (Make sure to have each row end in `\n` though).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick reply. I am new to Python and I don't if what am doing is correct, but the "other things" are the variables containing the other data from the CSV file. For example, if you take a look at the last row, the "other things" are holding each column in individually and are compare accordingly. In the fourth row, I have the variables TOS and UNS hold the data 10 and 6 (from the CSV) and print 143495 00210 309 TRS if the evaluation is not true; all in the same row.

Comment: Hey pandas, the "\n" solution does not work. It just creates more unwanted lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your input, this will read each line and compare column 3 with column 4, printing only the lines where they don't match.

```
import csv
import sys

with open('python.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
    for line in reader:
        docs,co,mic,tot,un,loc_fr,_ = line
        if int(tot) != int(un):
            writer.writerow([docs,co,mic,loc_fr])
```

Output:

```
143493,00210,309,TRS
143494,00210,309,TRS
143495,00210,309,TRS
```

Comment: Hey Mark, thank you that's exactly what I wanted. Now, how would I set the output to variables so can re-use the data.

Comment: @TonyBatista `a,b,c,d,e,f,_ = line`.  The extra unused variable `_` is because your original data ended in a comma, so it looks like another empty field.  I'll update the answer with that example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but this might help and answer your questions from the comments as well.

I have formatted your data like so & saved it into Python.csv as in your example:

```
143560,00210,318,2,2,'TRS'
143493,00210,309,6,4,'TRS'
143494,00210,309,6,4,'TRS'
143495,00210,309,10,6,'TRS'
```

Then, you can read this into pandas and easily process it

```
import pandas

#read the csv into a pandas Data.Frame
with open('python.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spreadsheet= pandas.read_csv(csvfile, names = ['DOCS','COS','MICS','TOTS','UNS', 'LOC_FRS'])

#now you can print rows of the spreadsheet like so
#e.g. if you want to get rows where TOTS is 6 as in your comment
print spreadsheet[spreadsheet['TOTS']==6]
```

you can find out how this indexing works more generally [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Comment: Hey, Patrick, I have done as you suggested but I am getting this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas',"  may pandas needs to be added?

Comment: Yes, you need to [install](https://packaging.python.org/installing/) that module as its not part of std python

Comment: I want Python to read the CSV that structure like this 143495,00210,309,10,6,TRS and compare the values 10 and 6 for equality. Then, in this case, if 10 is not equal 6 set the different variables with this values 143495 00210 309 TRS and print the results row by row.